# Insert Into Multiple Tables At Once

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am migrating data between two databases.  From the first database I am exporting a csv file that has the following columns:

```
Customer_Name
Contact_First_Name
Contact_Last_Name
Phone1
Phone2
Fax
```

I need to take this data and put it into the following tables for the new database:

```
Table: customer_contact
    contact_id  INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    first_name  VARCHAR(50)
    last_name   VARCHAR(50)
    customer_id INT
    PK = contact_id

Table: contact_phone
    contact_id INT
    phone_num  VARCHAR(15)
    in_use     BIT
    PK = contact_id, phone_num

Table: contact_fax
    contact_id INT
    fax_num    VARCHAR(15)
    in_use     BIT
    PK = contact_id, fax_num
```

My plan is to `BULK INSERT` the data from the csv into a temporary table, and then use that to do `INSERT`s into each of the other tables.

Since the main identifier for each contact if their first and last names, how do I insert the corresponding data into the phone and fax tables?  I am using SQL Server.

Comment: How are you planning to load the data? TSQL, Powershell or something else?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot that basic part >_<  Editting OP

Comment: @Goforebroke Simply put, I want to bulk insert into a temporary table with the csv data, and from there insert the data from the temp table into the tables on the new database

Comment: Insert to customer_contact from the temp table, OUTPUT the contact_id values, insert into the two other tables. Wrap all 3 statements in a transaction.

Comment: @JacobH This may work, I shall give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to have repeated rows to add more records in the tables PHONE and FAX? Or do you want to skip repeated rows?

Comment: @AMG Each phone/fax number should be connected to one contact, but each contact can have multiple phone/fax numbers.  that's how i tried to get the tables set up.

Comment: my question is this: suppose you have in row 1: JOHN DEER;JOHN;DEER;111111111;222222222;333333333 AND you have another row, lets say row 500: JOHN DEER; JOHN;DEER;444444444;555555555;666666666.  How do you want the Row #500 to be treated?... Do you want it to be skipped? or you want to add 2 more phone numbers and one more fax?

Comment: @AMG I would have it add 2 more phone numbers and 1 more fax

Comment: Ok. then check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution applies when you have repeated data in the CSV and you want to control what to do in every case. Since, there is nothing in your question about the following fields, I'm not including any logic for them:

```
customer_id INT, 
in_use     BIT
```

0 - create the tables you already declared in your question

1 - create a t_Bulk table having the exact structure of your cvs and execute the bulk copy

```
CREATE TABLE T_BULK (
Customer_Name VARCHAR(100),
Contact_First_Name VARCHAR(50),
Contact_Last_Name VARCHAR(50),
Phone1 VARCHAR(15),
Phone2 VARCHAR(15),
Fax VARCHAR(15)
);
GO
```

2 - With the T_BULK table already full, let's process each record:

```
DECLARE @ContactId int, @FirstName varchar(50), @LastName varchar(50), @Phone1 varchar(50), @Phone2 varchar(50), @Fax varchar(50)

    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY  
    FOR   
    SELECT Contact_First_Name, Contact_Last_Name, Phone1, Phone2, Fax
    FROM dbo.T_BULK


    OPEN MY_CURSOR  
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @FirstName, @LastName, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Fax
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN   

    //if the contact already exists we get the identity
    IF EXISTS (select contact_id from customer_contact where first_name=@FirstName and last_name=@LastName)
        select @ContactId = contact_id from customer_contact where first_name=@FirstName and last_name=@LastName

    //if the contact does not exit we need to insert and retrieve the new Identity value
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            insert customer_contact (first_name,last_name) values (@FirstName,@LastName)
            set @ContactId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END

    //now we continue with the phones and fax
    //insert only new phones
    INSERT contact_phone (contact_id,phone_num) 
    SELECT Id, Phone   
    FROM (select @ContactId as Id, @Phone1 as Phone UNION select @ContactId ,@Phone2) P  
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM contact_phone C WHERE C.contact_id = P.Id and C.phone_num = P.Phone); 

    //insert only new fax
    INSERT contact_fax (contact_id,fax_num) 
    SELECT Id, fax   
    FROM (select @ContactId as Id, @Fax as fax) F
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM contact_fax C WHERE C.contact_id = F.Id and C.fax_num = F.fax); 


        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @FirstName, @LastName, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Fax  
    END  

    CLOSE MY_CURSOR  
    DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Good luck

In order to include an additional field:

in the declare zone include an aditional variable: 
`@Extension`.

which you must include in both `FETCH NEXT` lines. Then you need to include that variable when inserting the phones, but in this case you need to check that phone2 is not equeal to phone1, just to ensure you don't have repeated phones:

```
    (select @contactId as Id, @Phone1 as Phone, @Extension as Extension 
UNION select @ContactId, @Phone2, null where @Phone2 <>@Phone1) P
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this response.  Just a quick question.  Let us suppose that there was another column to the CSV, that was an extension for the first phone number.  How would I program that into the insert if the extension field could be blank, and didn't apply to the second number? (Assume I added a column to the phone table for the extension that allowed for nulls).

Comment: check the answer....

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `KEEPIDENTITY` when you use the **BCP**, this way the bulk insert will use the identity values you already have and not the autoincrement SQL Server provides.

Also, use staging tables before insert to the definitive tables, this to validate data consistency and format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-identity-values-when-bulk-importing-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'd love to use `KEEPIDENTITY`.  However, problem is, there is no identity for the data rows I will be importing :|

Comment: ohh it is easier then.. you just need a staging table with the raw data as it comes from the csv, just add an identity PK and let it be autogenerated by SQL Server engine, then insert the data on the first table customer_contact using your new ID as key, then create an aggregate query to insert info on the other 2 tables (you will also need a surrogate key for each table as well), if this is ok, i will update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would accomplish the task assuming there are no data issues with your CSV file. I assume first_name, last_name uniquely identifies a person eg 1 row per person...(usually another identifier is needed like middle name or middle init or bday or SSN or some combination to handle diff individuals with same name

**1X Load**

1. Load the CSV file to a stage table that contains the needed columns via bulkinsert

BULK
INSERT STG_Contacts
FROM 'c:\contacts.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

2. Insert into customer_contact table from the stage table

--not sure how you plan to gen customer_id so default it to null

insert into customer_contact(first_name, last_name, customer_id)
select Contact_First_Name, Contact_LastName, NULL as Customer_ID 
  from STG_Contacts

3. insert into contact_phone table

-- default phone 1 to true phone 2 to false??

insert into contact_phone(contact_id, phone_num, in_use)
select b.contact_id, a.Phone1, 'True' as InUse
  from STG_Contacts a
  join customer_contact b
    on a.Contact_First_Name = b.first_name
   and a.Contact_Last_Name = b.last_name
where (Phone1 is not null and len(Phone1) > 0 )
union all
select b.contact_id, a.Phone2, 'False' as InUse
  from STG_Contacts a
  join customer_contact b
    on a.Contact_First_Name = b.first_name
   and a.Contact_Last_Name = b.last_name
where (Phone2 is not null and len(Phone2) > 0 )

4. insert into fax table

insert into contact_fax(contact_id, fax_num, in_use)
select b.contact_id, a.fax, 'True' as InUse
  from STG_Contacts a
  join customer_contact b
    on a.Contact_First_Name = b.first_name
   and a.Contact_Last_Name = b.last_name
where (fax_num is not null and len(fax_num) > 0 )

**Nightly loading...via SSIS or TSQL via SQL Agent**

1. Truncate the staging table
2. Load the staging table from csv w/bulk insert
3. Load the contact table with new rows and process updates
4. Load the phone and fax table with new rows and process updates

use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on how to use the merge statement to process new rows, updates and deletes.